# sas,how to randomly assign a patient to a clinic if he/she goes to multiple clinics

Tags: random, sas

I'd like to analyze compliance rate at clinic level,but I have a whole lot of patients that belong to multiple clinics.I'd like to randomly assign one clinic to each of such patients.Anyone knows how to do it? I read proc surveyselect, proc plan but not sure how to do it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to pick one of the clinics at random, `proc surveyselect` works fine.  Using made up `data have`, see the code below it.  `n=1` says pick one record per stratum.

```
data have;
do patient = 1 to 20;
  do clinic = 1 to ceil(3*rand('Uniform'));
    output;
  end;
end;
run;

proc surveyselect data=have out=want n=1 seed=12345;
strata patient;
run;
```

If the patient is at the same clinic multiple times, the chance of selection would be higher for that clinic; if you don't want that, first dedup by patient/clinic.

Answer (score 1):

For compliance rates you could study each clinic using all of their patients instead of attributing, or you could attribute based on dollars spent at each clinic.

To do random assignment, one way is to assign a random value to each member/clinic combination.  Then sort each patient on their random values.  Then only keep the largest random number which will be a completely random clinic.

```
/* Get unique combinations of clinic and patient */
proc sql;
create table clinicdata as
select distinct clinic, patient
from rawdata;
quit;

/* Give each combination a random value r */
data clinicrandom;
set clinicdata;
call streaminit(123); /* set random number seed */
r = rand("uniform");
run;

/* Sort each patient by that random number */
proc sort data = clinicrandom;
by patient r;
run;

/* Only keep the highest value combination */
data clinicfinal;
set clinicrandom;
by patient;
if first.patient;
run;
```